# Examples of wait/lock/obstruction-freedom and OOC methods

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm reading [akka documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.7/general/terminology.html#Non-blocking_Guarantees__Progress_Conditions_) and now I'm at the section about non-blocking guarantees. Here is the definition provided for these concepts:

> A method is *wait-free* if evey call is guaranteed to finish in a
>   finite number of steps
>
> *Lock-freedom* is a weaker property than wait-freedom. In the case of lock-
>   free calls, infinitely often some method finishes in a finite number
>   of steps.
>
> *Obstruction-freedom* is the weakest non-blocking guarantee [...]. a method is 
>   called obstruction-free if there is a point in time after which it
>   ecxecutes in isolation
>
> *Optimistic concurrency control* (OOC) methods are usually
>   obstruction-free. the OOC approach is that every participant tries to
>   execute its operation on the shared object, but if a participant
>   detects confilict from others it rolls back the modifications, and
>   tries again according to some schedule.

So, consider the following method:

```
public class MyClass{

    private final AtomicInteger ai = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public void method(){
        while(true){
            int current = ai.get();
            if(ai.compareAndSet(current, current + 1))
                 break;
        }
    }
}
```

What category we can put it to? I think it's *OOC* method (obviously by the definition) and an *Obstruction-freedom* one (obviously by the definition), but it's not a *Lock-freedom* one.

But I'm not quite sure about it, the definition of lock-freedomness is kind of blurred, especially the part of ***infinitely often some method finishes in a finite number of steps***. What is it supposed to mean? Couldn't you give me an example of *wait-free* and *lock-free* methods?

Comment: Idk what class that is but the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm#Lock-freedom) has a longer explanation

Answer (score 2):

**Wait-freedom**

Your method can not be classified under this category.
This is due to the fact that when multiple threads run the method() function one or more threads can make the other threads require more steps.
The issue is due to the fact that:

```
int current = ai.get();
// another thread can adjust the number between our statements!
if(ai.compareAndSet(current, current + 1)) // Returns true if the value of ai is still 'current'
    break;
```

> A method is wait-free if every call is guaranteed to finish in a finite number of steps.
>
> If a method is bounded wait-free then the number of steps has a finite upper bound.

Given infinite threads, the upper-bound would go to infinity.

**Lock-freedom**

According to http://www.cs.swan.ac.uk/~csdavec/HPC/11LockFreedom.pdf

> • At least one thread must be able to make progress at any
>   given time
>
> • Eventually, all threads must make progress
>
> • Given infinite time, infinitely many threads will progress

So you must guarantee at least one thread makes progress. Which is the case since the compareAndSet only updates the value if the value is still the same. Combined with the fact that if it is unchanged the code progresses (break).

So, at least one thread is guaranteed to make progress.

**Obstruction-freedom**

Refer to the link mentioned in the previous section. It states that:

> A single thread, with all other threads paused, may complete its
>   work.

Your code would fall under this category, since if only one thread is active for the duration of those 2 statements, it's guaranteed to end.

**Optimistic concurrency control (OCC)**

OCC seems is a special sub-case of obstruction-free. It does fall under this since if compareAndSet detects a change it cancels the updating of the number.

Your question about what "infinitely often some method finishes in a finite number of steps." means:

It essentially means the part I quoted in the lock-freedom section, since at every time that there is at least 1 process running the code, one process must make progress.

This means that given enough time all processes (infinite if the number of processes is infinite!) will make progress.

*** Conclusion ***

It is not classified wait-free.

It does classify as Lock-free, obstruction-free and OCC.

Comment: method() can't run forever, 1 thread is always guaranteed to succeed because the `if` can only fail if one thread suceeded (I don't think outside sources changing the value count, and even if, they couldn't change the value reliably enough)

Comment: Right, sorry. Let me re-phrase the answer.